# android activity crashing in

Tags: android

i have an activity that crashes randomly after the device resume from
a long period of sleep, the activity is forced to be landscape mode
only.  When the device resumes from sleep, the activity seems to be
redrawing itself in portrait mode, occupying half the horizontal view,
then have to force close it.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the following in your manifest in the activity definition?

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Not sure if the following is needed but I remember having to add it to the activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   // ignore orientation/keyboard change
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```